# Choosing fuse for 2S Li-po

Tags: protection, lipo, fuses, polyfuse

I have a 2S 8000 mAh Li-po battery I want to use as an external power source for my DSLR camera (Canon 7D Mark II). [Previously, I failed to power it with a power bank and a DC-DC converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523244/xl6009-boost-converter-as-8v-camera-dslr-external-power-supply-camera-not-tu), most probably due to a weak power source.

I know the best way to care for a Li-po battery is to use a BMS. I found some cheap BMSes also with balancing (AliExpress, eBay, etc.), but there is lack of proper datasheets and every product has the same specifications.

So I decided to keep it simple and directly for now. It will be charged with an external charger/balancer. Over-discharge should not be an issue, as my camera will shut off when the battery is drained. The camera's internal battery is 2S Li-ion.

I know that an unprotected Li-po can by dangerous, so I decided to at least use a fuse to protect it. I need advice on which fuse to choose. The requirements are:

- protect the battery if a short circuit happens;
- reversible when short circuit no longer exists;
- as low a voltage drop as possible.

The camera should draw at most 3 A @ 8 V plus some small power devices, so with sufficient reserve, 4 A @ 8 V is the max. output power. I went trough some PolySwitch datasheets for example, but I can't decide on my own if this kind of fuse is fast enough to protect Li-po.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want either an EFuse or a Overcurrent Detection IC. Like the names implies, these are devices that detects how much current is passing through your circuit and will disable the load if the current is too high.

**EFuse Pros**: Easy to intergrate into a circuit, small in size

**EFuse Cons**: Thermals could be an issue depending on the current draw, tolerance for overcurrent trip isn't as tight

**Overcurrent Detection IC Pros**: More accurate of a current trip point, main IC doesn't heat up due to low current draw, can select transistors for overcurrent trip

**Overcurrent Detection IC Cons**: Might be more expensive, requires more parts, slightly more complex design

It's going to be up to you to decide which one you want to use, but you may be able to use  EFuse if you're okay with the wider tolerance. As long as the internal resistance isn't too high, you probably won't have to worry too much about heat dissipation.

Comment: By ellectronic fuse - do you mean some simple circuit like this? https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/dc-electronic-fuse-circuit-diagram
Because I also found some IC from STM.

Comment: I meant something more like this: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2596.pdf?ts=1604372510890&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS2596

Comment: Now I understand. The particular IC you linked has max. current limit 2 A, so I guess it is not suitable for my use. But I found one which 
 can be set up to 6A (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps1663.pdf?ts=1604475078693&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.fi%252F). I like that I can also set undervoltage with such chip. But the major problem with this solution is soldering for me. I would need to have it soldered on custom fabricated PCB. Originally I intended to build some "trough-hole", but I understand by-hand solderability was not in my requirements. Thank you.